# Making boolean attribute false or true depending on which submit button the user clicks?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I added a draft attribute to my `Post` model:

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content",            :limit => 255
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "draft",                             :default => false
    t.datetime "published_at"
  end
```

Right now it appears as a checkbox:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysihtml5-textarea" %>

<%= f.label :category_id, "Select Category" %>
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name,
                        { prompt: 'Select Category' } %>

<%= f.label :draft %>
<%= f.check_box :draft %>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit "Create post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

I would like to modify the form so that instead of clicking the draft checkbox, the user can click either `Save as Draft` or `Publish` button (Like you do in WordPress).

I have no idea how to make those buttons influence the value of the `draft` attribute.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about using CoffeeScript or Backbone.js (gems available in RoR) to change the value of the draft attribute in the event of either button?

Comment: @Neeraj T Wouldn't that be a little bit an overkill?

Comment: There is another option: process the value of whichever button clicked in the controller itself and use it to influence the draft attribute.

Comment: I seem to recall facing this myself, but my memory's hazy. Does the `params` hash have an entry with key `"Commit"`?

Comment: @Chowlett Yeah, I made a "Save Draft" button and when I click it I see this: `"commit"=>"Save Draft"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a `submit` button, Rails will automatically include a `"commit"` entry in the `params` hash, which carries the text of the button clicked. You should be able to key off that in your controller.

Note that, last time I tried, there was a bug in `jquery-ujs` which meant this tactic didn't work for forms declared as `:remote => true`. However, that was a while ago and I did raise a bug report, so it may have been fixed subsequently.

Comment: I did something like this in my create action:   `if @post.save && params[:commit] == "Publish"
      @post.status = "published"
      flash[:success] = "Post published!"` the problem is that the post was already saved so `@post.status = "published"` become useless.

Comment: Not sure if it is hacky but I did this:  `if @post.save && params[:commit] == "Publish"
      @post.update_attributes(status: "published")`

Comment: Why not set `post.status` before saving? If the save fails, the status still won't be set.

Comment: Are you sure it won't be set? `@post.status = "published"` would be before `@post.save`

Comment: Certain. `@post.status = "published"` just sets the value in Rails' in-memory copy. It's only when you call `save` that the value is written to the DB. If validations fail, or the database rejects the `UPDATE`, the whole thing is rolled back.